# Excel to Outlook: .Send returns Run-time Error

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, runtime-error

This has been asked before, however, I have tested all of the prior solutions provided and none have worked, so I am asking here.

I have excel code that sends an email if a particular set of conditions are met. I have triple checked my data, and there has been no error there. Now the code worked fine a few days ago, and all of a sudden I am getting a `Run-Time error '287': Application-defined or object-defined error.` on the `.Send` line. When I use `.Display` instead, it works fine but obviously I have to manually send the email.

Here is my code:

```
Sub mailing()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet


        lastrow = Worksheets("2018").Cells(Rows.Count, "Y").End(xlUp).Row
        Dim rgRem1 As Range 'rg, Reminder 1
        Dim rgRem2 As Range 'Reminder 2
        Dim rgRem3 As Range 'Reminder 3
        Dim rgAssigned As Range 'rg2, days since assigned

        Set ws = Worksheets("2018")

        With ws
            lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
            Set rgAssigned = Range(.Cells(1, "X"), .Cells(lastrow, "X"))
            Set rgRem1 = Range(.Cells(1, "Y"), .Cells(lastrow, "Y"))
            Set rgRem2 = Range(.Cells(1, "z"), .Cells(lastrow, "z"))
            Set rgRem3 = Range(.Cells(1, "aa"), .Cells(lastrow, "aa"))
        End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")



    For Each cell In rgRem1
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        If cell.Value = "SENDING" Then      'try with less conditions first
            With OutMail
                .To = Cells(cell.Row, "V").Value
                .Subject = "WO# " & Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value & " -  Reminder"
                .Body = "Work Order: " & Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value & _
                    " has been assigned to you for " & Cells(cell.Row, "x").Value & " days and is not yet completed. Can you provide any updates?" & _
                    vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Region: " & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value & vbNewLine & _
                    "District: " & Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value & vbNewLine & _
                    "City: " & Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value & vbNewLine & _
                    "Atlas: " & Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value & vbNewLine & _
                    "Notification Number: " & Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value & vbNewLine
                '.ReadReceiptRequested = True
                .Send
            End With
            Cells(cell.Row, "Y").Value = Now
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If

        Next cell

    For Each cell In rgRem2
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        If cell.Value = "SENDING" Then      'try with less conditions first
            With OutMail
                .To = Cells(cell.Row, "V").Value
                .Subject = "WO# " & Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value & " - Reminder"
                .Body = "Work Order: " & Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value & _
                    " has been assigned to you for " & Cells(cell.Row, "x").Value & " days and is not yet completed. Can you provide any updates?" & _
                    vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Region: " & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value & vbNewLine & _
                    "District: " & Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value & vbNewLine & _
                    "City: " & Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value & vbNewLine & _
                    "Atlas: " & Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value & vbNewLine & _
                    "Notification Number: " & Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value & vbNewLine
                '.ReadReceiptRequested = True
                .Send
            End With
            Cells(cell.Row, "z").Value = Now
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If

        Next cell


    For Each cell In rgRem3
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        If cell.Value = "SENDING" Then      'try with less conditions first
            With OutMail
                .To = Cells(cell.Row, "V").Value
                .Subject = "WO# " & Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value & " - Reminder"
                .Body = "Work Order: " & Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value & _
                    " has been assigned to you for " & Cells(cell.Row, "x").Value & " days and is not yet completed. Can you provide any updates?" & _
                    vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Region: " & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value & vbNewLine & _
                    "District: " & Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value & vbNewLine & _
                    "City: " & Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value & vbNewLine & _
                    "Atlas: " & Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value & vbNewLine & _
                    "Notification Number: " & Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value & vbNewLine
                '.ReadReceiptRequested = True
                .Send
            End With
            Cells(cell.Row, "aa").Value = Now
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If

        Next cell



    'Set OutApp = Nothing                        'it will be Nothing after End Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'For Each cell In rgAssigned
        'If cell.Value = 25 And cell.Value <> "Completed" And cell.Value <> "Over 75 days since assigned" And cell.Value <> "" And Cells(cell.Row, "Y").Value = "" Then
        'Cells(cell.Row, "Y").Value = "SENDING"
        'End If

        'If cell.Value = 50 And cell.Value <> "Completed" And cell.Value <> "Over 75 days since assigned" And cell.Value <> "" And Cells(cell.Row, "Z").Value = "" Then
        'Cells(cell.Row, "Z").Value = "SENDING"
        'End If

        'If cell.Value = 75 And cell.Value <> "Completed" And cell.Value <> "Over 75 days since assigned" And cell.Value <> "" And Cells(cell.Row, "AA").Value = "" Then
        'Cells(cell.Row, "AA").Value = "SENDING"
        'End If
    'Next cell
End Sub
```

**I've tried several solutions suggested online including:**

1. Checking my trust center settings--they are set as seen in [this image](https://image.ibb.co/m37jNq/trust.png).
2. Using `.SendKeys` (both `.SendKeys "%S"` and `.SendKeys "^{ENTER}"`)
3. Using `.SendMail`
4. Enabling all the References (in Excel) related to Microsoft Scripting Runtime, Outlook, and object-libraries
5. Running the code both with Outlook open and with Outlook closed
6. I am avoiding a mail merge solution as this excel is meant to be used by multiple people, each with the same trust center settings but different mail merge settings

I have this email automation in several of my macros and none of them are working. My security has not changed and my computer has not had a major update since the last time I used this excel. If anyone has any patches or information that can help me--*that does not include or only repeat the solutions I have already tested*--I would greatly appreciate it. I asked this question on mrexcel.com/forum regarding a similar but different code and am reaching out here as I have yet to receive any answer.

**EDIT:**

Here is more information regarding my References in Excel:

[image: References]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue years ago due to our email policy not allowing remote sending so I added code to Outlook to send drafts upon saving then instead of `.send` in Excel I used `.save`, This runs on my VM so I am guaranteed it will not accidentally send something I am drafting, I wouldn't recommend this on your normal use machine. It's a strange solution but it works.

Outlook code:

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts).Items
Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
EmailOutlookDraftsMessages
End Sub

Public Sub EmailOutlookDraftsMessages()
Dim lDraftItem As Long
Dim myOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myFolders As Outlook.Folders
Dim myDraftsFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set myOutlook = Outlook.Application
Set myNameSpace = myOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolders = myNameSpace.Folders
Set myDraftsFolder = myFolders("insight@brickworks.com.au").Folders("Drafts")
For lDraftItem = myDraftsFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
If Len(Trim(myDraftsFolder.Items.Item(lDraftItem).To)) > 0 Then
    myDraftsFolder.Items.Item(lDraftItem).Send
End If
Next lDraftItem
Set myDraftsFolder = Nothing
Set myNameSpace = Nothing
Set myOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hope that helps, sing out if you get stuck.

Comment: Before I try it, is this something everyone would have to hard code change in their individual outlook applications? I just want to be sure because I'll write some instructions to add this in if that's the case

Comment: also upon using the .save function, this appeared in the 'To' section of my draft email: ` </O=ENOVA/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=1D7DF0ED82D24F52A584C2007A34B288-DOE, J (CON> ` (assume J Doe, is my name)

Comment: It would need to be in the outlook of any machine where the macro runs and sends emails. I have no idea what that string is, Mine just sends the email from the host machines default outlook email address

Comment: Just keep in mind, this is ALWAYS ACTIVE in the outlook session, any draft you create on that outlook will automatically send, if outlook autosaves a draft when you have only half written an email, IT WILL SEND IT, This isn't an issue for me as it's on a VM so there is no danger of accidental sending.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm going to edit it so it only sends drafts that have a particular string in the title. But I do have a question, where did you place this in the outlook VBA? in a module or in the ThisOutlookSession? I have not used VBA from outlook before.

Comment: Yeah whack it in ThisOutlookSession. The hints is a great idea, I did that in the past when autodownloading files I email my server, it only saves things from me with a specific string in the title.

Answer (score 0):

If it works to you a few days ago perhaps it's blocked by 'smtp' port or 'ssl' verification ? it can caused by the isp server also if it exist..
one last point that i can think about .. maybe the run time service itself falling in the scripting routine (if it happend there is a log file..)
if it happend i'm offer to reinstall the outlook run time or the debugger service or both..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, could provide me with some resources or further explanation? Perhaps how to troubleshoot this? Thank you!

Comment: for checking the smtp settings you can chek this link: https://www.mailjet.com/support/how-do-i-change-my-smtp-settings-in-outlook,98.htm  
for the ssl you can check the Certificate Center of windows
and for the log file it should be in the TEMP directory at windows files the full path appears in the events at mangment tools

Answer (score 0):

Huge thanks goes out to [Dan Donoghue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4556996/dan-donoghue) who created this code and helped me place it in the correct place: the ThisOutlookSession in Outlook VBA. I tweaked it a little, so that it only send drafts that have a recipient and contain a certain text string included in the subject. I'm hoping to find a way to tweak it so that my email doesn't need to be manually input.

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
    Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts).Items
    Set objNS = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    EmailOutlookDraftsMessages
    End Sub

    Public Sub EmailOutlookDraftsMessages()
    Dim lDraftItem As Long
    Dim myOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolders As Outlook.Folders
    Dim myDraftsFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set myOutlook = Outlook.Application
    Set myNameSpace = myOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolders = myNameSpace.Folders
    Set myDraftsFolder = myFolders("R.E.L.s_email@fake.com").Folders("Drafts")
    For lDraftItem = myDraftsFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Len(Trim(myDraftsFolder.Items.Item(lDraftItem).To)) > 0 And InStr(myDraftsFolder.Items.Item(lDraftItem).Subject, "WO# ") > 0 Then
        myDraftsFolder.Items.Item(lDraftItem).Send
    End If
    Next lDraftItem
    Set myDraftsFolder = Nothing
    Set myNameSpace = Nothing
    Set myOutlook = Nothing
    End Sub
```